# How to integrate Swagger no config setup with Jersey 2

Tags: maven, jersey, swagger

I'm trying to do a barebones Swagger setup with a Jersey 2 project hosted on Tomcat 8.5. I first generated the jersey project with the following snippet from the Jersey getting started guide (https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/getting-started.html):

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-webapp
  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false
  -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=simple-service-webapp -Dpackage=com.example \
  -DarchetypeVersion=2.27
```

Then I added the Swagger dependencies from the swagger getting started guide (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Getting-started):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

When hit the api at http://localhost:8080/simple-service-webapp/webapi/myresource I get the correct response. When I hit http://localhost:8080/simple-service-webapp/webapi/openapi.json I get a 404 Not Found.

Any ideas?

Here's what my pom looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>simple-service-webapp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>simple-service-webapp</name>

<build>
    <finalName>simple-service-webapp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
        <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.27</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still need to register the [OpenApi resources](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/tree/26d72bf5fd2d54e5e514ddcf3861d125d2f95b42/modules/swagger-jaxrs2/src/main/java/io/swagger/v3/jaxrs2/integration/resources). These are the JAX-RS resource classes that serve up the JSON. Since you are using web.xml for your configuration, you can simply add the swagger package to the list of packages to scan.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>
            com.example,
            io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2.integration.resources
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Notice I added the `io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2.integration.resources` package to the list, delimited by comma. This will tell Jersey to scan that package, and it will discover and register both the [`AcceptHeaderOpenApiResource`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/v2.0.0/modules/swagger-jaxrs2/src/main/java/io/swagger/v3/jaxrs2/integration/resources/AcceptHeaderOpenApiResource.java#L17) and the [`OpenApiResource`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/v2.0.0/modules/swagger-jaxrs2/src/main/java/io/swagger/v3/jaxrs2/integration/resources/OpenApiResource.java#L18). The difference between the two is that the former serves up the path `/openapi` and the data format is determined by the `Accept` header in the request, and the latter serves up the path `/openapi.{type:json|yaml}`, where the data format is determined by the extension (.json or .yaml) in the path.

Comment: Can You propose java config for that?