# Can we Integrating Swagger with JAX-RS with out creating JSON configuration file?

Tags: spring-boot, jax-rs, swagger, swagger-ui, dropwizard

I have been using swagger for a while with spring boot applications. It is very easy with spring since i only have to specify the package info.

But recently i was going through a few documents on how to integrate swagger with JAX-RS, i found it requires more involvement from developer by specifying api information's on a JSON.

Do we have any other solution?

Comment: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Getting-started

Comment: @PaulSamsotha That involves a JSON, hmm i think JAX-RS can be integrated with SWAGGER only if there is a JSON configuration unlikely spring boot.

Comment: No it doesn't. I don't see JSON anywhere in the link. Did you even go through it step by step?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52124650/2587435